# DataBinding to a checkbox not working correctly

Tags: c#, checkbox, data-binding

I have a problem using DataBinding to a checkbox in C#. Checkbox does not reflect the value of the object it is bind to.

I used `checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", cb, "t", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)` to bind a simple data source to an object, cb. The the bool property `"t"` in the object updates based on the checkbox checked state, but the checkbox check state does not reflect the object state (`cb.t`).

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        test cb = new test();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cb.t = false;

            checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", cb, "t", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cb.t = true;
            //checkBox1.Refresh();
            //checkBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public class test
    {
        public bool t { set; get; }
    }
}
```

if i click button1 the state of the checkbox does not change; however, the if i i set the cb.t =  true in the constructor when the form loads the checkbox checked state is the same as the value of cb.t.  thanks for the help.

Comment: The test class needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`. Okay. So, where and how does your `test` class raises property change notifications when the value of the `t` property changes? Hint: Look at some guide/tutorial about implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.1) interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not being notified of updates when your property changes. See -
[How To: INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface)

Try making these changes -

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class test : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _t;
        public bool t {
            get { return _t; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _t)
                {
                    _t = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that works. I tried similar thing for a combobox, but it didnt work as expected.  I tried "comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", _systemSetttings, "field1", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);", but the combo box did not get updated until i click on the button or even the checkbox.

Comment: I added filed1 to the test class.  private int _field1;
        public int field1 {
            get { return _field1; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _field1)
                {
                    _field1 = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as "correct" if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: i fixed it, i was updating the field1 from a different thread.